# Fast API app to docker container connection refused

Tags: docker, api, dockerfile, containers, fastapi

I am trying to deploy my FastAPI app to a docker container (P.S. I am a beginner in using docker). I used the below code. Without the DB, this code is working fine in the docker container. However, when I try to try to connect to DB, the path "URL:port/" is showing connection refused. I used the exact steps as mentioned in [uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker)

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pymongo import MongoClient


app = FastAPI()

client = MongoClient('localhost', port=27017)
db = client.safetypointer


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    all_users = db.users.find({}, {"_id":0})
    return {"Hello": "World" , "allUsers": all_users}
```

Comment: are you sure your fastapi container can see the mongo db?

Comment: How can I test this?

Comment: Where is the database running?  `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container", and your database is probably somewhere else.

Comment: The mongo database is running in localhost. How can I make the container to see the mongo db?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: No. I have a mongo container and another fast API container. I want to connect them so that the fast API container listens the mongo container.

Comment: You should use your host ip instead of localhost. Try setting your machine's ip. https://itsfoss.com/check-ip-address-ubuntu/ for ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Local host should likely be replaced with the name of your mongo container.  I would also recommend taking a look at docker-composer as it can make deploying two connected containers easier.

Here is a link to an example with flask it would be similar with fastapi:
[awesome-compose](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/nginx-flask-mongo)